# Applescript working natively, but not in filemaker

Tags: applescript, filemaker

I'm trying to save a pdf as text. The following code works when I run it in scripteditor, but not when I run it in filemaker ( I've never had a problem before converting my applescripts to run in a filemaker step ).

```
activate application "Adobe Reader"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Adobe Reader"
        click menu item "Text..." of menu 1 of menu item "Save As" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Are you sure it works? One mistake I've made before is the 3 dots in the "Text..." menu item name. Some menu items actually use 3 periods while others use an ellipsis (you can type that with option-semicolon). So make sure you have the proper one to match that menu item.

Comment: Regulus, post that as an answer so that I can give you some credit! Filemaker took the liberty of changing my dots to an ellipsis which is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible source of error in this type of command is the 3 dots in the **"Text..."** menu item name. Some menu items actually use 3 periods while others use an ellipsis (you can type that with option-semicolon). I've used the wrong form before so please make sure you are using the correct form for your menu item.

The only way to know for sure is to try both and see which works. Normally an ellipsis is used so it's best to try that form first.